# Resource file is missing exception, but it is there

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I've an (old) .NET application which I have made some changes to (not to the files that have anything to do with this problem.)

Somewhere in the code (IssueDetail.aspx.cs) I have this, which always worked:

```
title = GetLocalResourceString( "RadTabDetails.Text" );
```

I have and IssueDetail.aspx.resx with this line:

```
<data name="RadTabDetails.Text" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Details</value>
</data>
```

Now I get an Exception:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture. Make sure "IssueDetail.aspx.resources" was
>   correctly embedded or linked into assembly
>   "App_LocalResources.issues.cdcab7d2.gyzl0com" at compile time, or that
>   all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

That is prety weird, because it IS on the server. And that is not even the weird part. I can actually see the translations working. So the file Is there AND the software is reading it.

On my local environment everything is working correctly, the problem only occurs on the ACC environment. I've locally build with ACC configuration, and the problem doesn't occur. So it looks like an problem of the server (or maybe even the build server) but I can't think of any settings that I can check.

I've found some threads about this problem, but then the issue was that the resource file wasn't working (what the exception also says) So i've checked the build action for the resx file and it is *Embedded Resource*, as it should.

Any idea what to check is appreciated!

Comment: Does it have .Resource file ?

Comment: It has a .resx file, which should be fine.

Comment: What is the IIS version ? have you tried added culture info in web.config ?